# What destroyed the walls of Jericho?

Tags: tanach

What destroyed the walls of Jericho in Joshua 6-20? The Shofar and the screams? Are there any explanations in rabbinical comments? I did not find any, apart from a contradictory explanation of the Talmud (Berakhot 54b) where it is said that the walls did not collapse but were swallowed up but without giving any explanation.

Shalom

Comment: Wasn't it a miracle?

Comment: Rav Hutner seems to imply as follows. The walls of Yericho represent the ability of the people of Yericho to define their own *reshus* (/ way of doing things). The fall of the walls of Yericho showed that this *reshus* was *nisbatel* by the *kedushas ha'aretz*. So the *tefillos* of the *benei yisrael* and the blowing of the shofar were *tefillos* that the *reshus ha'kedushah* in *Eretz Yisrael* should be unified and all other alien *reshuyos* in *Eretz Yisrael* should be *nisbatel*.

Comment: it was a nes. Hashem did it.